# How to correctly implement drag n drop tree?

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, tsx

I have a data structure, which is a tree of departments, it is necessary to implement a tree in which you can drag child elements (child elements are in the subs array) Example structure:

```
[{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "tes",
        "code": "tes",
        "subs": [
            {
                "id": 7,
                "name": "tesg",
                "code": "tesG",
                "subs": [
                    {
                        "id": 11,
                        "name": "tews",
                        "code": "tesD",
                        "subs": [
                            {
                                "id": 12,
                                "name": "tes",
                                "code": "tesA",
                                "subs": [
                                    {
                                        "id": 10,
                                        "name": "tesn",
                                        "code": "tesN",
                                        "subs": [],
                                        "head": {
                                            "id": 178,
                                            
                                            "name": "sdasd",
                                            "surname": "asd",
                                            "middleName": "a",sdasd
                                            "login": "a",sdasdads
                                            "departmentCode": "tes"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                               `

There are also 2 isles: one implements a component of the element tree, and the other has helpers;


`  const generatedArray: number[] = [];
  const generateUniqueId = (): number => {
    const random = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (99999 - 10000) + 10000);
  
    if (!generatedArray.includes(random)) {
      generatedArray.push(random);
      return random;
    } else {
      return generateUniqueId();
    }
  };
// Transform raw JSON from backend and add uniqueIds needed for frontend
export const transformRawJSONToAddUniqueIds = (tree: any) => {
  if (!tree) return [];

  return tree.map((node: any) => {
    const newNode = {
      ...node,
      id: generateUniqueId(),
    };

    if (node.subs) {
      newNode.subs = transformRawJSONToAddUniqueIds(node.subs);
    }

    return newNode;
  });
};


const findNodeByUniqueIdAndRemoveFromTree = (tree: any, targetId: any) => {
  let removedNode;

  const walkOnTree = (tree: any, targetId: any) => {
    const filteredTree = tree.filter((node: any) => {
      if (node.id === targetId) {
        removedNode = node;
        return false;
      }

      return true;
    });

    return filteredTree.map((node: any) => {
      const { subs, ...nodeWithoutSubs } = node;

      const returnObj = { ...nodeWithoutSubs, subs: [] };

      if (subs) {
        returnObj.subs = walkOnTree(subs, targetId);
      }

      return returnObj;
    });
  };

  return [removedNode, walkOnTree(tree, targetId)];
};
// Insert given node into node with given uniqueId
const insertGivenNodeIntoNodeWithGivenUniqueId = (tree: any, nodeToInsert: any, whereToInsertId: any) => {
  const walkOnTree = (tree: any, nodeToInsert: any, whereToInsertId: any) => {
    return tree.map((node: any) => {
      const { subs } = node;
      console.log(subs, nodeToInsert, whereToInsertId)
      const newNodeState = { ...node };

      if (node.id === whereToInsertId) {
        newNodeState.subs = [
          ...subs,
          nodeToInsert,
        ];
      } else if (subs && subs.length) {
        newNodeState.subs = walkOnTree(subs, nodeToInsert, whereToInsertId);
      }

      return newNodeState;
    });
  };

  return walkOnTree(tree, nodeToInsert, whereToInsertId);
};

// Move node with given uniqueId to another node
export const moveNode = (tree: any, whatToMoveId: any, whereToMoveId: any) => {
  //@ts-ignore
  const [
    nodeWithGivenId,
    treeWithoutNodeWithGivenId
  ] = findNodeByUniqueIdAndRemoveFromTree(tree, whatToMoveId);

  return insertGivenNodeIntoNodeWithGivenUniqueId(
    treeWithoutNodeWithGivenId,
    nodeWithGivenId,
    whereToMoveId
  );
};

export const sortTree = (tree: any) => {
  const walkOnTree = (tree: any) => {
    return tree.map((node: any) => {
      const { subs, ...nodeWithoutSubs } = node;

      const newNodeState = { ...nodeWithoutSubs };

      if (subs && subs.length) {
        const sortFunc = (a: any, b: any) => {
          if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
          if (a.name > b.name) return 1;
          return 0;
        };

        newNodeState.subs = walkOnTree([...subs].sort(sortFunc));
      }

      return newNodeState;
    });
  };

  return walkOnTree(tree);
};export const OrganizationHierarchy: React.FC = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const list = useAppSelector(departmentListHierarchySelector, shallowEqual);
  const [treeData, setTreeData] = useState<any>();
  const employees = useAppSelector(employeeListSelector, shallowEqual);
  const [nowDraggingUniqueId, setNowDraggingUniqueId] = useState<any>();
  const [nowDragOverUniqueId, setNowDragOverUniqueId] = useState<any>();
  const [nowDragOverType, setNowDragOverType] = useState();
  const treeWrapperRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getEmployeeAll());
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getDepartmentsHierarchy());
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTreeData(list);
  }, [list]);

  const handleDragStartNodeRow = (e: any) => {
    setNowDraggingUniqueId(+e.currentTarget.dataset.id);
    setNowDragOverUniqueId(+e.currentTarget.dataset.id);
  };

  const handleDragEnterNodeRow = (e: any) => {
    if (nowDraggingUniqueId !== +e.currentTarget.dataset.id) {
      setNowDragOverUniqueId(+e.currentTarget.dataset.id);;
    } else {
      setNowDragOverUniqueId(nowDraggingUniqueId);
    }
  };

  const handleDragEndNodeRow = () => {
    if (
      nowDraggingUniqueId !== nowDragOverUniqueId &&
      nowDragOverType === "folder"
    ) {
      let newTree;
      newTree = moveNode(treeData, nowDraggingUniqueId, nowDragOverUniqueId);
      newTree = sortTree(newTree);
      setTreeData(newTree);
    }
    setNowDraggingUniqueId(undefined);
    setNowDragOverUniqueId(undefined);
    setNowDragOverType(undefined);
  };

  const handleDragOverNodeRow = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  const handleDropNodeRow = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    handleDragEndNodeRow();
  };

  const buildTree = (tree: any) => {
    const mappedNodes = tree.map((node: any) => {
      return (
        <ul
          data-id={node.id}
          data-type={node.type}
          draggable={true}
          onDragStart={handleDragStartNodeRow}
          onDragEnter={handleDragEnterNodeRow}
          onDragOver={handleDragOverNodeRow}
          onDrop={handleDropNodeRow}
          onDragEnd={handleDragEndNodeRow}
        >
          <div data-unique-id={node.uniqueId} data-value={node.name}>
            {node.name}
          </div>
          {buildTree(node?.subs)}
        </ul>
      );
    });

    return mappedNodes;
  };

  return (
    <ul ref={treeWrapperRef} draggable>
      {treeData !== undefined ? buildTree(treeData) : <div>Нет данных</div>}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

The problem is that I don't understand where events don't work and what the trouble could be

I tried using third-party libraries, but they don't fit my version of react, so you need to make this component without using libraries

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.